# How to set Imageview as an object?

Tags: android, object, imageview

I am working with carousel view. With one layout, I put four images.
And I want to set each image as an each object because I want to set a different method when each image is clicked.

```
    ImageButton product_photo = (ImageButton) l.findViewById(R.id.myoffer_image);

    product_photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.myoffers_0);

    product_photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.myoffers_1);

    product_photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.myoffers_2);

    product_photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.myoffers_3);
```

I tried like the code below..but surely it makes an error..

```
ImageButton one = product_photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.myoffers_0);
```

I don't know if my question is clear..but if you reply something to know more clear, I will explain it!

Here is pageadapter class!

```
public class Myoffers_PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

private Myoffers_LinearLayout cur = null;
private Myoffers_LinearLayout next = null;
private Myoffers context;
private FragmentManager fm;
private float scale;

public Myoffers_PagerAdapter(Myoffers context, FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    this.fm = fm;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) 
{
    // make the first pager bigger than others
    if (position == Myoffers.FIRST_PAGE)
        scale = Myoffers.BIG_SCALE;         
    else
        scale = Myoffers.SMALL_SCALE;

    position = position % Myoffers.PAGES;
    return Myoffers_Fragment.newInstance(context, position, scale);
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{       
    return Myoffers.PAGES * Myoffers.LOOPS;
}

//@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
        int positionOffsetPixels) 
{   
    if (positionOffset >= 0f && positionOffset <= 1f)
    {
        cur = getRootView(position);
        next = getRootView(position +1);

        cur.setScaleBoth(Myoffers.BIG_SCALE 
                - Myoffers.DIFF_SCALE * positionOffset);
        next.setScaleBoth(Myoffers.SMALL_SCALE 
                + Myoffers.DIFF_SCALE * positionOffset);
    }
}

//@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {}

//@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}

private Myoffers_LinearLayout getRootView(int position)
{
    return (Myoffers_LinearLayout) 
            fm.findFragmentByTag(this.getFragmentTag(position))
            .getView().findViewById(R.id.root);
}

private String getFragmentTag(int position)
{
    return "android:switcher:" + context.pager.getId() + ":" + position;
}
```

}

Main class!

```
public class Myoffers extends FragmentActivity {
public final static int PAGES = 4;
public final static int LOOPS = 1000; 
public final static int FIRST_PAGE = PAGES * LOOPS / 2;
public final static float BIG_SCALE = 1.0f;
public final static float SMALL_SCALE = 0.5f;
public final static float DIFF_SCALE = BIG_SCALE - SMALL_SCALE;

public Myoffers_PagerAdapter adapter;
public ViewPager pager;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myoffers);

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myviewpager);

    adapter = new Myoffers_PagerAdapter(this, this.getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(adapter);

    pager.setCurrentItem(FIRST_PAGE);

    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

    pager.setPageMargin(-100);
}
```

}

Fragment code
    public class Myoffers_Fragment extends Fragment {

```
protected static final String TAG = "Philips";
FileOutputStream mOutputStream; 
private String id;

public static Fragment newInstance(Myoffers context, int pos, float scale)
{
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt("pos", pos);
    b.putFloat("scale", scale);

    return Fragment.instantiate(context, Myoffers_Fragment.class.getName(), b);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }

    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.mf, container, false);

    int pos = this.getArguments().getInt("pos");
    TextView tv = (TextView) l.findViewById(R.id.text);
    tv.setText("Product " + pos);


    /*
     * Put images with Hard-Coding
     */
    {
    ImageButton product_photo = (ImageButton) l.findViewById(R.id.myoffer_image);

    product_photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.myoffers_0);

    product_photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.myoffers_1);

    product_photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.myoffers_2);

    product_photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.myoffers_3);

    }


    Myoffers_LinearLayout root = (Myoffers_LinearLayout) l.findViewById(R.id.root);
    float scale = this.getArguments().getFloat("scale");
    root.setScaleBoth(scale);

    return l;
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little vague, but I will respond to the best of my ability--if I am misunderstanding anything, feel free to let me know and I will edit my answer accordingly.

Since 'carousel' is not part of the android SDK, it is a little difficult to be sure what you need to do (it would help if you showed what class/library you are using for this carousel). However, chances are that it will be using this class or a subclass of it in the implementation: [AbsListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html)

Every listview-based class has some method that is called when an item is clicked (here, it is performItemClick). When it is called, it will in turn call the onItemClick method of the associated [AdapterView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html). The adapter is something that you (or the library you are using) created, filled with your data to be displayed, and attached to the ListView.

By registering an AdapterView.OnClickListener, you can specify what behavior a click on a list item at any given index will cause.

Without more details about your carousel, I cannot provide any more code-specific help. However, if you post more info I would be happy to update my answer!

Comment: Really appreciate your reply!!!! Actually, i know my info is full of lack. But I couldnt post all my carousel related code here..that's why...I have three classes relative to carousel view which are main, pageadapter, linearlayout and fragment.

Comment: I just changed Button to ImageButton to put certain images i have. And I want to make method that if an image is clicked, the method would implement..

Comment: are you checking..now?..or..gone..?

Answer (score 0):

ImageButton is a class, and you created an object of that type called 'product_photo'.  Then you create another called 'one'.  The problem is that you tried to assign a method to one rather than create a new ImageButton. Instead you should have

```
ImageButton one = new ImageButton();
one.setImageResource(R.drawable.myoffers_0);
```

Whether or not 'one' needs to be something in your layout that you get with findViewById or not (likely you do) is up to your application.